Animal repellent circuit for cows and goats
I want to create an animal repellent circuit for my school project but I'm having some problems designing the circuit. The circuit does not produce any sound frequency.
NB: We are not allowed to use any microcontrollers.
I have:

Power circuit (How can I add a battery which will be charged by the solar power?)
Comparator (R1 and C3 mimic PIR sensor output)
Oscillator (555 timer)
Switching circuit
Sound output


In the circuit I have a battery which may be the solar power in a voltage regulator which produces about 4.668 V for the circuit.


LM358 is an op-amp, not a comparator, and the output is push-pull not open-drain. Do you think connecting it directly to TR/TH on the 555 is going to work?

I suggest you squeeze your circuit to make it more readable like this: https://i.sstatic.net/py47wkfg.png

Hm, in my experience, cows are, at best, curious about things making noises, and not sensitive to high-pitched noises (could blow a dog whistle at them and they'd just look at you and wonder whether they should come to the fence and inspect you; most of them do like being talked to in a low voice). Goats will absolutely come and try to eat whatever you put next to them, and I wouldn't trust making it noisy would not increase their willingness to try. But interesting approach!

none of the component values seem to make any sense to me.

@Tlotlo What is your question?

i was intrested in designing a circuit that could output a certain frequency that could be used to chase away animals. Now that is what i tried to come up with and unfortunately it does not work. No sound comes from the sounder. Now i wanted to know what errors or wrong things i might have done in this circuit

@MarcusMüller Thanks, i will try a different approach
